# Create container function call not working

Tags: node.js, express, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to create container using azure storage in Node.js and Express.js. Below is my code:

```
'use strict'
var azure = require('azure-storage')

var Blob = (function () {
  function Blob (opts) {
    this.container = opts.container
    this.blobSvc = azure.createBlobService(opts.account, opts.key)
    this.createContainer(this.container)
  }

  Blob.prototype.createContainer = function (name) {
    this.blobSvc.createContainerIfNotExists(name, function (error, result, response) {
      if (!error) {
      }else {
        throw error
      }
    })
  }
  return Blob
}())

module.exports = function (opts) {
  return new Blob(opts)
}
```

Problem is that **this.blobSvc.createContainerIfNotExists(...)** is not called at all. I tried to figure out why, but unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code and it works fine on my side. Without your error message and what you tried, it's difficult to know what's wrong. However, the following is my test result you can take that as reference.

**The folder structure:**

\blob.js

\testCreateContainer.js

---

***blob.js***

```
'use strict'
var azure = require('azure-storage')

var Blob = (function () {
  function Blob (opts) {
    this.container = opts.container
    this.blobSvc = azure.createBlobService(opts.account, opts.key)
    this.createContainer(this.container)
  }

  Blob.prototype.createContainer = function (name) {
    this.blobSvc.createContainerIfNotExists(name, function (error, result, response) {
      if (!error) {
      } else {
        throw error
      }
    })
  }
  return Blob
}())

module.exports = function (opts) {
  return new Blob(opts)
}
```

***testCreateContainer.js***

```
var blob = require('./blob.js')

blob({container: 'testcontainer', account: '<account name>', key: '<access key>'})
```

---

After running the following command `node testCreateContainer.js`, the container named "testcontainer" would be created.

[image]